# Recommend Course of Action?

Tags: windows, drivers, bios, asus

I have an Asus VivoBook that came with windows installed on it.  For amusement and profit, I have been hacking away trying to to serve a website from behind a wireless router at my house.  At some point, I needed to reinstall Ubuntu on the machine, but the wireless card drivers appear to have been corrupted or deleted.

After further meddling, the best solution seems to be to shell out for a Windows disk and use that to get the drivers I need, then just reinstall Ubuntu.  Does anyone have any other suggestions?  I've tried to find the actual drivers and put them on a flash drive, but the drivers themselves are elusive.  If anyone knows specifically where I can find them, or has fixed this before, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: how are we supposed to help you find drivers if we don't even know what wireless card you have? post the output of `lspci`, please.

Comment: I solved my problem.  Basically, I tried installing Ubuntu server edition on a laptop, but that doesn't come with any wireless drivers.  Installing the desktop edition will properly configure the wireless card.

Answer (score 1):

Having the windows drivers won't do you any good in Ubuntu, because linux can't use them.

A quick search turned up [one vivobook model](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/printpage/ASUS-VivoBook-X202E-Laptop/1766) which uses an Atheros AR9485 wifi chip.  This is supported by the [ath9k kernel driver](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/ath9k), which should be included with any stock linux kernel.

> the wireless card drivers appear to have been corrupted or deleted

You have not explained *why* you believe this (and again, if you are referring to the windows drivers, they are irrelevant under linux), which implies it is some kind of imaginative guess.  If you want help diagnosing your wireless issues, you'll have to get specific about the nature of the problem.

Comment: Agreed on the likely chipset, but it's possible the OP had it set up under NDISwrapper. I used to have to use a Windows driver on my laptop back in the day.

Comment: @Comintern I actually hadn't forgotten about that, it just seems really unlikely to me; I'm surprised to learn that NDISwrapper is, in fact, still around.  I also think it (used to get) used in a lot of cases as an XY solution -- user is frustrated by wireless problems and figures an OEM driver will help, in the process of doing everything again coincidentally solves wireless problem, but the out of tree driver actually makes the situation worse by introducing subtle problems of its own.  Anyway, point taken.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'd never recommend using it unless absolutely no other options exist.

Comment: IIRC that's the intended purpose -- for cases where no in-tree driver exists.

Comment: Well, I typically work under the assumption that drivers come with the installation media.  Somehow, I got it into my head that there must be some BIOS-related part of the wireless driver that somehow got walloped while experimenting with the equipment.  This is not the case.  I simply was installing a version of Ubuntu that did not come with the needed driver.  An install of desktop edition fixed this.